# How to build with Maven In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am a beginner in Maven and trying to build my first app with Maven using the latest version of Eclipse. After right-clicking the pom.xml file choosing Run-As and Maven Build, I get a window with the title "Edit Configuration and Launch". This window has 3 text areas "Goals", "Profiles", "User settings".

What should I enter into these text areas to run my application successfully?

### Edit

My application is a simple console application in Eclipse so I just want the output from the Main class to appear on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your project, goals can be one of the life cycle phases [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to achieve. 
To start with you can use "install" or "compile". The other two can be left empty for now.

Comment: I used "compile" and then "install". By testing each separately some text shows on the console that BUILD is SUCCESS but i don't see the ouput from my program. I have also edited my question. thanks for your answer

Comment: Maven is only used to build your code.. if you want to run your Main class, you should select the Particular class -> Right click and select the option "Run as" -> select Java Application

Answer (score 1):

We can attach maven-antrun-plugin:run goal to test phase. This will allow us to echo text messages for different profiles. We will be using pom.xml to define different profiles and will activate profile at command console using maven command.

Assume, we've created following pom.xml in C:\MVN\project folder.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.companyname.projectgroup</groupId>
   <artifactId>project</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                  <tasks>
                     <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
            <copy file="src/main/resources/env.test.properties" tofile
            ="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.properties"/>
                  </tasks>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

And assume, we've created following properties file in C:\MVN\project\src\resources folder.

> env.properties
>
> environment=debug env.test.properties
>
> environment=test env.prod.properties
>
> environment=prod

Now open command console, go to the folder containing pom.xml and execute the following mvn command. Pass the profile name as argument using -P option.

```
C:\MVN\project>mvn test -Ptest
```

For better clarification: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_profiles.htm

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous answer, I would most often use 2 goals: `clean install` or `clean compile`

The `clean` remove all files generated by the previous build.

The `install` will run phases 1-7 below which copies the resulting jar into your local maven repository (usually a .m2 directory in your home directory) so that it is available and can be referenced as a dependency to other maven projects.

The `compile` will only run phase 1-2 below which compiles your code, but stops before running any configured tests.

Other options are copied from the Maven site below for convenience.

> A Build Lifecycle is Made Up of Phases
>
> Each of these build lifecycles is defined by a different list of build
>   phases, wherein a build phase represents a stage in the lifecycle.
>
> For example, the default lifecycle comprises of the following phases
>   (for a complete list of the lifecycle phases, refer to the [Lifecycle
>   Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)):

1. **validate** - validate the project is correct and all necessary
   information is available
2. **compile** - compile the source code of the
   project
3. **test** - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit
   testing framework. These tests should not require the code be
   packaged or deployed
4. **package** - take the compiled code and package it
   in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
5. **integration-test** - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
6. **verify** - run any checks to verify
   the package is valid and meets quality criteria
7. **install** - install
   the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in
   other projects locally
8. **deploy** - done in an integration or release
   environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for
   sharing with other developers and projects.